# static variables as Header of TemplateFields in grdiv view asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, static, headertext

I have the asp.net application where I am having the editable grid view with the edit,Delete,Add options. this grid having as usual Template fields. I have also a static Class that having static string variables. I want to keep these static variable's value as Header text of Template Field. 
So I have imported my constant class's namespace by :

```
<%@ Import Namespace="ConstantManagerNamespace" %>
```

Then I tried for same column:

```
1. <asp:TemplateField HeaderText=<%=ConstantManager.Name%>>

2. <asp:TemplateField HeaderText='<%=ConstantManager.Name%>'>

3. <asp:TemplateField HeaderText=<% ConstantManager.Name %>>

4. <asp:TemplateField HeaderText='<% ConstantManager.Name%>'>

  all probable syntax to access my constant variable value but
```

I got Parser error:

```
Literal content ('<asp:TemplateField HeaderText=') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection'.
```

how to do this ?

Comment: Any update here please ?? is my question understandable ?? i  have doubt about it

Comment: Hello....any reply please here.....

Comment: Does it work if you change from static to non-static? error doesn't look like it is related to using static vars.

Comment: Did my answer (below) help you?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because you are trying to embed server-side control/value inside another server-side control. That is not directly possible in asp.net, unless you use databinding or custom expression builder.

For your exact situation, you need to create a custom expression builder, which returns the value from your static class.

Final result should look something like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<$ ConstantManager:Name >">
```

Which is absolutely allowed withing aspx file as long as you have defined the custom expression builder with `"ConstantManager"` prefix.

The actual example of creating the custom expression builder can be found here: [ExpressionBuilder Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.expressionbuilder.aspx).

**ADDITION**:

Also, I think databinding will also work, but it seems to me not the exact solution for this kind of situation.

Just use this syntax in the aspx markup:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<# ConstantManager.Name >">
```

And, on page load, call:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.DataBind();
}
```

Personally I don't like this solution because of the `Page_Load` part. Anyway, this does not need to have anything special declared/coded if compared to the custom expressions.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Its better to bind the static class varibles in the GridView RowDataBound Event,

check the Row type is Header ie.

```
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
       e.Row.Cells[0].Text = ConstantManager.Name;                  
    }
```